# What can I control with keyspace?

Tags: database, memory, io, distributed-database, yugabytedb

Can I control the amount of **CPU**, **memory** and **IO resources** per keyspace in yugabyte DB?

Comment: Your question doesn't provide anywhere near enough detail for even any *attempt* at a reasonable answer.  Would someone posting, "Yes!" do you any good?

Answer (score 2):

A [keyspace in YCQL](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/api/ycql/ddl_create_keyspace/) is a namespacing mechanism (similar [to a database in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-createdatabase.html)). Database objects like tables, indexes live inside of a keyspace. YugaByte DB doesn't provide QoS or resource control (CPU/memory/etc.) at a per-keyspace level.

You can also use keyspaces [as a mechanism for access control](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/api/ycql/ddl_grant_permission/) over a group of related objects inside the keyspace.

For example,

`GRANT ALL ON KEYSPACE k to ROLE r;`